# Dataframes to CSV (on a loop) taking a long time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please be aware that I installed Python 2 days ago and wrote my first two codes copying and pasting other codes I found, changing some things here and there.

I have a code that:
1- Creates a Pandas Dataframe
2- Loop some data, creating new dataframes that are "merged" (not sure this is the right word) to the Dataframe created in step 1

On my first code, Step 1 created Dataframe df0 and on Step 2, it created a Dataframe df that was merged to df0 using:

```
df0=df0.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

The final Dataframe was written in a CSV file. But that was taking a long time (around 3 hours) and Python tells me that pandas.append will be suspended soon.

On my second code, Step 1 creates a Dataframe and writes it directly to a CSV suing:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv',mode='w',index=False,header=True)
```

and Step 2 creates a new dataframe on each step of the loop and writes it to the CSV file created in Step 1 using:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```

This speeded the proccess of writing all the data in a CSV file (to around 20 minutes).

But this is still a long time for me, since I have to do this a few times throughout the day.

There are around 10.000 dataframes written to this CSV. They have only 5 columns and the number of rows varies from 0 to 75.000. The final CSV has around 3 million rows, so not a big deal for Python I guess.

Is there a smarter and faster way to do what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: you can test `polars`

Comment: Yes, `pd.append` is deprecated and `pd.concat` should be used instead. It sounds like you need to create your dataframes separately, but to combine them you should put them all in a list and use `pd.concat`. Then you can write the entire file at one time.

Comment: Hey, Bert!I tried using Polars as More suggested. It seems pretty much faster indeed, but my coding skills didn’t allow me. Yesterday I read about a dataframe collection and put it to work. The idea is exactly what you suggested. I create X thousand dataframes and in the end I merge them all at onde, instead of merging df1 to df2, then df3 to df1+df2, etc (which made no sense, honestly, but…)

Comment: So I ended with a 3 minute execution! Which is great! Specially when my first code took 3 hours. I would like to thank you guys for the help!! Really!